# Parsing JSON data gives "undefined" in front of first result

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a problem parsing JSON data for a zip code application. The following code throws an "undefined" in the results for no apparent reason:

**"undefined16652, 16654, 16660,"**

```
var myZipcodes;
$.each(data, function(i, zipData){
 if (zipData.zip){
    myZipcodes += zipData.zip;
    myZipcodes += ", ";
 }
});
$('#results').html(myZipcodes);
```

Here's what my object looks like (first item opened):

```
 [Object, Object, Object]
      0: Object
        city: "HUNTINGDON"
        country: "US"
        distance: "0"
        lat: "40.49"
        lng: "-78.01"
        locationText: "Huntingdon, PA"
        state: "PA"
        zip: "16652"
        __proto__: Object
      1: Object
      2: Object
      length: 3
      __proto__: Array[0]
```

I also tried a FOR loop, but it gave the same results:

```
var myZipcodes;
var length = data.length;
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       myZipcodes += data[i].zip;
       myZipcodes += ", ";
    }
```

If I try to display the results of just one object value, it returns just the zipcode without "undefined". The problem happens when I try to iterate through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that `myZipcodes` was not initialised and most probably not defined before actual use.

```
var myZipcodes = '';  // <-- locally defined
                      // ... and initialised with ''
$.each(data, function(i, zipData) {
    if (zipData.zip) {
        myZipcodes += zipData.zip;
        myZipcodes += ", ";
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't include in the code above, but myZipcodes is actually initialized. Sorry about that. I'll change it in my post above. Despite the initialization, the problem still persists.

Comment: @user2755541 It is *not initialised* with initial value. Please see that in my answer I mentioned about `defined` and `initialised with ''`.

Comment: Yes, that's it! I initialized it but didn't give it a value. Thanks!

Comment: @user2755541 *Define* means that you locally create a variable with `var myVar;`, while *initialise* means that you set an initial value for the defined variable, i.e. `myVar = 'value';`.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have defined `myZipcodes`, but not initialized it.

Chances are you are doing:

```
var myZipcodes;
```

This creates `myZipcodes`, but doesn't give it a value.  It's value is `undefined`.  So when you append to this, its value is first "converted" to a string.  So, you get `'undefined'`.

What you want to do is:

```
var myZipcodes = '';
```

Define it *and* give it a value.

Comment: That's it! I initialized it, but I didn't give it a value.

Comment: Glad I could help! :-D